# Is there a way to create .arb files on runtime in flutter based on api

Tags: api, flutter, runtime, language-translation

I was looking for a solution to create dynamic content which will be available based on  different languages, but for adding new language, I don't want to publish new/update app every time.

.ARB files is what is used to create new Language translation, in short they are labels. Is it possible to create and store this .arb files on runtime via api as api can be updated easily and we don't need to update the app on store.

Comment: Although it isn't a complete solution, I recommend `attranslate` to speedup the synchronization of ARB files: https://github.com/fkirc/attranslate Such semi-automated tools can be hugely important to get translation workflows up to speed.